# sw-toolbox or indexedDB

Tags: browser-cache, indexeddb, progressive-web-apps, offlineapps

What is the best strategy to store an api response that contains a list of data while building a PWA?

1. to cache the response using sw-toolbox
   or
2. to save it in indexedDB and return from it when offline.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer with this [Offline Storage for Progressive Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa) documentation. Here are some recommendations for storing data offline:

> - For the network resources necessary to load your app while offline, use the [**Cache API**](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/cache-api) (part of [service workers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-worker/)).
> - For all other data, use [**IndexedDB**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) (with a [promises wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb)).

You may also check this [page](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/live-data-in-the-service-worker#using_indexeddb_and_the_cache_interface) for the difference between [Storing data with IndexedDB](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/live-data-in-the-service-worker#storing_data_with_indexeddb) and [Storing assets in the Cache interface](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/live-data-in-the-service-worker#storing_assets_in_the_cache_interface).

Answer (score 1):

IndexedDB is a browser standard (browsers native API), that is widely supported by all major browsers and [Google's recommendation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa) for storing offline API kind of data.

As [explained here](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/sw-toolbox/), Service Worker Toolbox (or SW-Toolbox) provides some simple helpers for use in creating your own service workers. It uses IndexedDB internally. You can refer to the code [here](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-toolbox/blob/3590616292deb0d8eb727d795e080edc8bc7f151/lib/idb-cache-expiration.js#L27). Think of it like a jQuery solutions, which simplifies things which is otherwise still possible with added effort.

Note that sw-toolbox is on its way to retire, in favor of [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/). 
SW-Toolbox non-critical bugs are unlikely to be addressed per Chrome team and its been 8 months since any feature added to it. So you have all reason to not choose SW-toolbox and consider [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/), if you are looking for a helper library to implement Offline store to your web app.